# How to sort NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionaries?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

Here is my code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"contact_name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName];    
arrayOfDictionary = [arrayOfDictionary sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Obviously this doesn't work because `arrayOfDictionary` is a `NSMutableArray`.  I've looked around a lot and all the sorting I see with arrays of dictionaries is done with non mutable arrays.  Can anyone shed some light on how I can do this with an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Why do you say "Obviously this doesn't work"?  The main problem you have in the above code is that you throw away the sorted array.  (But if you bother to look at the spec for NSMutableArray you'll see that there are several 'sort in place" options.  RTFM.)

Comment: So then obviously it doesn't work... The only thing I was looking for was sortUsingDescriptors.                                    [arrayOfDictionary sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
Gets it to sort a NSMutableArray in place

Comment: And that was clearly documented in the NSMutableArray spec, which you didn't check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sortUsingDescriptors` if you want to sort your Mutable array.

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayOfDictionary = [arrayOfDictionary sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors] mutableCopy];
```

While not the best way to do it, will get you what you want...

Comment: This will return a (new) *immutable* array, not a mutable array.

Comment: Even if `arrayOfDictionary` is a `NSMutableArray`, the return value of `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` is an `NSArray`.

Comment: @MartinR which is why the _mutableCopy_ at the end, I hoped would return a NSMutableArray?

Comment: But using mutableCopy is a lot more work than simply sorting the original array in place, which can be done using sortUsing....

Answer (score 0):

If your array of dictionaries contains the key `contact_name` your code should almost work. Please note the simplification below requiring much less code.

Please note that you can create a new array from a mutable or non-mutable array with `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors`. You can also sort a mutable array with `sortUsingDescriptors`.

Thus:

```
NSArray *newArray = [arrayOfDictionary sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
   @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"contact_name" ascending:YES]]];

// if you need it mutable:
NSMutableArray *mutableArrayOfDictionary = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:newArray];
```

or

```
[mutableArrayOfDictionary sortUsingDescriptors:
   @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"contact_name" ascending:YES]]];
```